# Screen scraping a data from a Web Site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am building my first chrome extension and trying to display some forex rates on my google chrome extension.But I am finding myself struck with cross domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem.Is There a way to scrap a data from cross domain web page using jquery.For your kind info the third party webpage I am referring does not support webservice :(

Please find below the code I am trying to use in my chrome extension to scrap the current forex rate.Please help . Thanks in advance

```
$.ajax({
 url: "http://someCrossDomain.forexrate.html",
 dataType: 'text', 
 success: function(data) { 
 console.log($("h2:first").text()); 
} });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're setting host [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) in your extension manifest:

Answer (score 1):

For a packaged app, you can do ajax requests without running into the cross-site access restrictions. I'm not 100% sure that it is needed, but if you are still having trouble, then make sure you add `http://*/` to your permission section in the manifest (or restrict it further if you only need to make calls to certain sites). For hosted applications, you can not do cross-site requests without either a cooperating server (which specifically allows it), or using a proxy on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the cross-site the best option (IMHO) is to write a web-service call to handle the request, then call it from your jQuery call. But if you can't write a web service to handle in a bit bigger pickle.

Comment: Hey Mate Thanks for your quick reply.... I will try writting a web service for it. Is there by any chance a way to scrap the cross domain webpage using javascript.if so please guide me by pointing a reference if you could...

Comment: No the cross-domain protection was put in place to prevent hijacking. If it wasn't there i could load all kinds of nasties behind the scenes and the user wouldn't be the wiser. By doing it this way it ensures the owner of the site knows what is going into his site.